# Configuring TCP keepalive after accept

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

After the `accept()` on a socket, I'm trying to configure the TCP keepalive.

```
SockConnected = accept(SockListen, &RemoteAddr,
                   &RemoteLen);
/* A bit of checking goes here */
if (setsockopt (SockConnected , SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE,
                            (ST_CHAR *) &sockopt_on, sizeof (int) ) )
{
   /* Error logging */
}

if (setsockopt(SockConnected , IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (char*)&(sockopt_tcp_keep_idle), sizeof(sockopt_tcp_keep_idle)))
{
    /* Error logging */
}
if (setsockopt(SockConnected, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, (char*)&(sockopt_tcp_keep_intvl), sizeof(sockopt_tcp_keep_intvl)))
{
    /* Error logging */
}
if (setsockopt(SockConnected, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, (char*)&(sockopt_tcp_keep_cnt), sizeof(sockopt_tcp_keep_cnt)))
{
    /* Error logging */
}
```

After calling `getsockopt()` for all four properties, everything seems alright. I've checked in Wireshark and there are no Keep alive packets being sent. I had to change `SOL_TCP` to `IPPROTO_TCP`, because when calling `setsockopt()` for `TCP_KEEPIDLE` it was returning errno 92 (Protocol not found).

I'm doing the same thing after calling `socket()` for an outgoing connection, and it's working perfectly.

I'm using C and Linux.

Is there any reason why `setsockopt` may not be working after an accept?

Comment: The values you're setting may not be the actual values being used. The platform can adjust them. Use `getsockopt()` to find out what values are actually being used, and then see whether what's happening agrees with that. NB I believe you can do all this once, on the listening socket, whence it will be inherited by all accepted sockets.

Comment: I tried it on the listening socket too, with no luck. I'll double check the return values of  `getsockopt()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example. If it works for you, you can use it as a reference.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#define check(expr) if (!(expr)) { perror(#expr); kill(0, SIGTERM); }

void enable_keepalive(int sock) {
    int yes = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &yes, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int idle = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int interval = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &interval, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int maxpkt = 10;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &maxpkt, sizeof(int)) != -1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    check(argc == 2);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
    check(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &addr.sin_addr) != -1);

    int server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    check(server != -1);

    int yes = 1;
    check(setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    check(bind(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != -1);
    check(listen(server, 1) != -1);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        int client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        check(client != -1);
        check(connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != -1);
        printf("connected\n");
        pause();
    }
    else {
        int client = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
        check(client != -1);
        enable_keepalive(client);
        printf("accepted\n");
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output (`tcpdump` reports keepalive packets every second):

```
$ ./a.out 127.0.0.1 &
[1] 14010
connected
accepted

$ tcpdump -n -c4 -ilo port 12345
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:00:35.173892 IP 127.0.0.1.12345 > 127.0.0.1.60998: Flags [.], ack 510307430, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 389745775 ecr 389745675], length 0
18:00:35.173903 IP 127.0.0.1.60998 > 127.0.0.1.12345: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 389745775 ecr 389745075], length 0
18:00:36.173886 IP 127.0.0.1.12345 > 127.0.0.1.60998: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 389745875 ecr 389745775], length 0
18:00:36.173898 IP 127.0.0.1.60998 > 127.0.0.1.12345: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 389745875 ecr 389745075], length 0
4 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Thank you! I was configuring everything before the `listen()` and after the `accept()`. If I do it just after `accept()`, keepalive it's being enabled.

Answer (score 6):

`SO_KEEPALIVE` should be used with `SOL_SOCKET`, not `IPPROTO_TCP` or `SOL_TCP`. See [socket(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) and [tcp(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp).

So try this:

```
int val = 1;
setsockopt(SockConnected, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &val, sizeof(val));
```

I guess `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and similar options are just ignored if `SO_KEEPALIVE` was not set correctly, and `SOL_TCP` is a synonym for `IPPROTO_TCP`.

If it does not help, consider posting a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It turns out it was a typo when opening the question here. I checked my code, and as you say, `SOL_SOCKET` is used with `SO_KEEPALIVE`.

Comment: Well, then I have no ideas. I suggest to start from minimal example that reproduces your program and do error checking for all system calls, so others can try it and help you. I'll post a minimal example that works for me in a moment.

Comment: typo: program -> problem